# Requests dict from cookiejar issue with escaped chars

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm running into some issues getting a cookie into a dictionary with python. It seems to be all escaped somehow even after running the command provided by requests.

```
resp = requests.get(geturl, cookies=cookies)
cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(resp.cookies)
```

and this is what cookies looks like

```
{'P-fa9d887b1fe1a997d543493080644610': '"\\050dp1\\012S\'variant\'\\012p2\\012S\'corrected\'\\012p3\\012sS\'pid\'\\012p4\\012VNTA2NjU0OTU4MDc5MTgwOA\\075\\075\\012p5\\012sS\'format\'\\012p6\\012S\'m3u8\'\\012p7\\012sS\'mode\'\\012p8\\012Vlive\\012p9\\012sS\'type\'\\012p10\\012S\'video/mp2t\'\\012p11\\012s."'}
```

Is there any way to make the characters unescaped in the value section of P-fa9d887b1fe1a997d543493080644610 become escaped and part of the dict itself?

Edit:

I would like the dictionary to look something like:

```
{'format': 'm3u8', 'variant': 'corrected', 'mode': u'live', 'pid': u'NTA2NjU0OTU4MDc5MTgwOA==', 'type': 'video/mp2t'}
```

Comment: For clarity could you post what you would like the dictionary to look like?

Comment: Posted what I'd like it to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with the Python [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) format for data serialisation. Once you have evaluated the expression, so escaped characters are unescaped, you need to load the pickle from a string using the `pickle.loads` function.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> import ast
>>> pickle.loads(ast.literal_eval("'''" + cookies.values()[0] + "'''")[1:-1])
{'pid': u'NTA2NjU0OTU4MDc5MTgwOA==', 'type': 'video/mp2t', 'variant': 'corrected', 'mode': u'live', 'format': 'm3u8'}
```

Comment: Hey would you know how to keep the top level dict in this case as well? Or better yet, some documentation describing what exactly is going on here haha. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you mean like `{'P-fa9d887b1fe1a997d543493080644610': {'pid': ...}}` ?

Comment: Yea - I'm arriving at a point where I need to learn the constructs of python I guess. so cookies.values()[0] grabs the first value of the dictionary -> then ast.literal_eval takes that value and decodes the pickled version. Am I getting that right?

Comment: ast.literal_eval safely evaluates a string representation of python data & returns the orignal python datatype. `d = eval("{'a': 3}") ` assigns a dictionary to d. In your case, you needed to do something like `ast.literal_eval("'\\050dp1\\012S...'")` in order to get `'(dp1\nS...'`.  The  `'(dp1\nS...'` is the pickled data. `pickle.loads` takes that string and turns it into a dict.

Comment: Read more here https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html .